# Create a side menu that loads on top of the view controller

Tags: ios, residemenu

I want to create a side menu that should load on top of the main view controller.

I have done `RevealViewController`, but thats not what I want. When the side menu comes my main view controller should be blur.

[image]

This is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

cant you just add a blur layer between the two VCs every time you call your `presentSideMenu` and remove on `removeSideMenu`?

Comment: I just want it to be blur slowly when the main view going to right side

Comment: I don't understand the main view on top of the other view or the other way around?